# Angular 7 error of insert and retrieve both are together

Tags: data-binding, angular7

**manage-customers.component.html**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
  <h1 class="h2">Manage Customers</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Customer ID</label>
      <input type="text" #cID class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Customer ID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Customer Name</label>
      <input type="text" #cName class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Customer Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Customer Address</label>
      <input type="text" #cAdd class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Customer Address">
    </div>
    <button type="reset" id="save"(click)="saveCustomer(cID.value,cName.value,cAdd.value)"  class="btn btn-primary">Save Customer</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-dark">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Customer ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let customers of customer">
  <td>{{customers.id}}</td>
  <td>{{customers.name}}</td>
  <td>{{customers.address}}</td>
  <td><button (click)="deleteCustomer(customers)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

**manage-customers.component.ts**

```
    saveCustomer(id: string, name: string, address: string) {
        this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customers/', new Customer(id, name, address), {observe: 'response'})
          .subscribe(response => {
              if (response.status === 201) {
                alert('Save');
                this.loadAllCustomers();
              } else {
                alert('Fail to save the customer');
              }
            }
          );
      }

loadAllCustomers(): void {
    this.http.get<Customer[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customers').subscribe(customers1 => {
      this.customer = customers1;
    });
  }
```

**Description**

- When I insert a value in DB also I want to update my web page. But the problem is data is properly entered the DB but not update my page. I can't understand why this?

**Error Image**
I use an angular 7 to build an interface and console error

[Console error](https://res.cloudinary.com/sewwandi/image/upload/v1561897501/Screenshot_224.png)

**Backend Code**

```
package com.sliit.paf.payment.controller;

import com.sliit.paf.payment.dto.CustomerDTO;
import com.sliit.paf.payment.service.custom.ManageCustomersService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private ManageCustomersService customersService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<CustomerDTO>> findAllCustomers(){
        List<CustomerDTO> customers = customersService.getCustomers();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("X-Count",customers.size() + "");
        System.out.println(customers);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<CustomerDTO>>(customers,httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id:C\\d{3}}")
    public CustomerDTO findCustomer(@PathVariable("id") String cId){
        CustomerDTO customer = customersService.findCustomer(cId);
        return customer;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id:C\\d{3}}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") String cId){
       customersService.deleteCustomer(cId);
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String saveCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO){
        customersService.createCustomer(customerDTO);
        return customerDTO.getId();
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/{id:C\\d{3}}",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity updateCustomer(@PathVariable("id") String cId, @RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO){
       if (cId.equals(customerDTO.getId())){
           customersService.updateCustomer(customerDTO);
           return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
       }else {
           return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Constructor of Component, inject changeDetectorRef and call detectchange method.

```
  constructor(
            private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
          )
```

---

```
loadAllCustomers(): void {
this.http.get<Customer[]> 
               ('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customers').subscribe(customers1 => {
     this.customer = customers1;
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

Comment: It is not working. I use this method to do a delete function and it's working

Comment: Ok, just saw your console error, looks like your model JSON parsing error. Could you please check your model object returning  json value from server or share your  model object

Comment: I think you ask my backend code. Yes, when I saving a detail I return primary key(id).

Comment: Yes I asked about backend code, Problem is converting  or parsing your backend model to Json.

Comment: yes, that is an error of my backend I return a none JSON value and problem is converting a value in JSON.it's my mistake. thank your help. I solved it.